# XSLT: Need Conditional based data using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use xslt in one of my product and i am stuck up on below issue.

As a response I am getting an XML which has some fields, More likely there are two main List Node `Header` and `Details`, `Details` is main data return by processing and `Header` has coded and other data related to output, In case `error code` is `70`, which means, this is error, other error codes are treated as successful.

XML Response Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <subroot>
        <data>
            <Header>
                <SCode>1</SCode>
                <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
                <ErrorCode>00000000</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDesc>This is OK</ErrorDesc>
            </Header>
            <Details>
                <accountNumber>1111X</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
                <Total>10000</Total>
                <Interest>10</Interest>
                <NewFlag>N</NewFlag>
            </Details>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Header>
                <SCode>1</SCode>
                <StatusCode>12</StatusCode>
                <ErrorCode>70</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDesc>This is ERROR</ErrorDesc>
            </Header>
            <Details>
                <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
                <Total>1000</Total>
                <Interest>12</Interest>
                <NewFlag>Y</NewFlag>
            </Details>
        </data>
    </subroot>
</root>
```

Now Output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <subroot>
        <data>
            <Details>
                <accountNumber>1111X</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
                <Total>10000</Total>
                <Interest>10</Interest>
                <NewFlag>N</NewFlag>
            </Details>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Details>
                <ErrorCode>70</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDesc>This is ERROR</ErrorDesc>
                <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
            </Details>
        </data>
    </subroot>
</root>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample input XML and the desired output shared, you can do the following to achieve the results.

Start with an *identity transform* template that will copy the structure as-is to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Using `<xsl:for-each>` on the `<Header>` node and using the node's `position()` as a reference, appropriate account information can be captured in the output. Below is the XSLT for reference with the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Header">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ErrorCode = '70'">
                        <Details>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ErrorCode" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ErrorDesc" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="../Details[$pos]/accountNumber" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="../Details[$pos]/accountType" />
                        </Details>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../Details[$pos]" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<root>
    <subroot>
        <data>
            <Details>
                <accountNumber>1111X</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
                <Total>10000</Total>
                <Interest>10</Interest>
                <NewFlag>N</NewFlag>
            </Details>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Details>
                <ErrorCode>70</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDesc>This is ERROR</ErrorDesc>
                <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber>
                <accountType>D</accountType>
            </Details>
        </data>
    </subroot>
</root>
```